# Compare two Complex Objects in c#

Tags: c#, .net, object, reflection, compare

I am trying to compare two objects and want to identify the difference in objects.

It works fine if I don't use `List`. But when I use `List`, Although the `List` in both objects are equal, it says it's not equal and go to check for `List` difference. Since, for now, I don't have the condition for list comparison it crashes and gives me this exception `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: 'Parameter count mismatch.'`

I have taken help from one of the stackoverflow post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504879/comparing-nested-object-properties-using-c-sharp). Here is my code which I have written so far.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Employee emp1 = OldEmployee();

        Employee emp2 = NewEmployee();

        var list = GetDifferingProperties(emp1, emp2);

        foreach (var s in list)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public static IList<string> GetDifferingProperties(object source, object target)
    {
        var sourceType = source.GetType();
        var sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties();
        var targetType = target.GetType();
        var targetProperties = targetType.GetProperties();

        var result = new List<string>();

        foreach (var property in
            (from s in sourceProperties
             from t in targetProperties
             where s.Name == t.Name &&
             s.PropertyType == t.PropertyType &&
             !Equals(s.GetValue(source, null), t.GetValue(target, null))
             select new { Source = s, Target = t }))
        {
            // it's up to you to decide how primitive is primitive enough
            if (IsPrimitive(property.Source.PropertyType))
            {
                result.Add(property.Source.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var subProperty in GetDifferingProperties(
                    property.Source.GetValue(source, null),
                    property.Target.GetValue(target, null)))
                {
                    result.Add(property.Source.Name);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static bool IsPrimitive(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string)
            || type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(int?)
            || type == typeof(double) || type == typeof(double?)
            || type == typeof(bool) || type == typeof(bool?)
            || type == typeof(Guid) || type == typeof(Guid?)
            || type == typeof(DateTime) || type == typeof(DateTime?);
    }

    public static string GetPropertyDisplayName(PropertyInfo pi)
    {
        var dp = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
        return dp != null ? dp.DisplayName : pi.Name;
    }

    private static Employee NewEmployee()
    {
        var contactDetail = new ContactDetails();
        contactDetail.ContactNumber = "123456789";

        var employeeAddress = new Address();
        employeeAddress.AddressLine1 = "Microsoft Corporation";
        employeeAddress.AddressLine2 = "One Microsoft Way";
        employeeAddress.City = "Redmond";
        employeeAddress.State = "WA";
        employeeAddress.Zip = "98052-6399";
        employeeAddress.ContactDetails = new List<ContactDetails>() { contactDetail };

        var employee = new Employee();
        employee.FirstName = "Bill";
        employee.LastName = "Gates";
        employee.MiddleName = "Middle Name";
        employee.IsActive = true;
        employee.JoinDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 15);
        employee.ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 15);
        employee.EmployeeAddress = employeeAddress;
        return employee;
    }

    private static Employee OldEmployee()
    {
        var contactDetail = new ContactDetails();
        contactDetail.ContactNumber = "123456789";

        var employeeAddress = new Address();
        employeeAddress.AddressLine1 = "Microsoft Corporation";
        employeeAddress.AddressLine2 = "One Microsoft Way";
        employeeAddress.City = "Redmond";
        employeeAddress.State = "WA";
        employeeAddress.Zip = "98052-6399";
        employeeAddress.ContactDetails = new List<ContactDetails>() { contactDetail };

        var employee = new Employee();
        employee.FirstName = "Bill";
        employee.LastName = "Gates";
        employee.MiddleName = "Middle Name";
        employee.IsActive = true;
        employee.JoinDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 15);
        employee.ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 15);
        employee.EmployeeAddress = employeeAddress;
        return employee;
    }
}

public class ContactDetails
{
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<ContactDetails> ContactDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public Address EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

If I comment out the line `employeeAddress.ContactDetails = new List<ContactDetails>() { contactDetail };` from oldEmployee and newEmployee, it works fine, and if there is any difference in EmployeeAddress it identifies it, and if there isn't any difference it doesn't. But if I uncomment this line `employeeAddress.ContactDetails = new List<ContactDetails>() { contactDetail };` it takes out EmployeeAddress as it has difference, although it doesn't. Can some one please suggest what I am missing, I have spent a lot of time to identify the issue.

My Target to Achieve is, to make a list of properties that has a difference in Employee Object, for Example,

1. If `FirstName` in `Employee` has difference `result` list should
   contain only FirstName
2. If `FirstName` in `Employee` and `AddressLine1` in `EmployeeAddress` has difference `result` list should contain (FirstName, EmployeeAddress)
3. Similarly, If `FirstName` in `Employee` and `ContactNumber` in `ContactDetails` which is a List in Address has difference `result` list should contain (FirstName, EmployeeAddress), In this case result list still contains `EmployeeAddress` because `ContactNumber` is in EmployeeAddress which is in Employee, So our main focus is to get parent Properties that has difference is source and target object.

Point 1 and Point 2 are working as Expected. Iff I comment out `employeeAddress.ContactDetails = new List<ContactDetails>() { contactDetail };` because it causing exception and also it coming with change although it doesn't have any change in source and target.

Any help would be highly appreciated, or you can suggest me some other way of implementation too.

Comment: Using reflection to compare is not a good choice. Overload `Equal` and compare it should be better. I assume you don't need to compare `Employee` and `string`. Your problem here is reflection getting reference of list and each list is different, but content could be the same.

Comment: How come you aren't overriding Equals for each object?

Comment: @LouisGo, yes overload equal would be a better idea, but I don't want to overload equal of my all entities. My current comparison object contains more than 25 entities some are single entities and some are List entities.

Comment: The correct way will be overriding Equal (and GetHashCode), then compare Lists with SequenceEqual (after you ordered them too I guess). Modifying GetDifferingProperties to handle IEnumerables by going inside the members is possible if you insist on not overriding Equal.

Comment: yes @Martheen, I am looking for Modifying GetDifferingProperties to handle List, is there any way to add a condition for GenericListType and check if the lists are equal or not? No matter if they are ordered or not.
liike new List<Contact>{new contact () {a: 1, b: 2}, new contact() {a: 3, b:4}} and new  List<Contact>{new contact () {a: 3, b:4}, new contact() {a: 1, b: 2}} are equal in my case.

Comment: What do you mean by *"GenericListType"*? Do you mean `IList`?

Comment: Then you could check if a propert is an IList, then compare contents of list and ignoring order. But you might get tripped by it in a long run. For example: what would happen if you have an List<ComplexType> ? Recursively calling this compare and it might get you in stackoverflow.

Comment: @RufusL I meant IList<AnyType>

Comment: @LouisGo you are right I think I might go in StackOverflow exception comparing the objects and list recursively. Could you please explain how could I achieve my target of getting the difference in Main Object Properties by overriding Equal?

Comment: @MustafaGaziani Check msdn for [Generate Equals and GetHashCode method overrides in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Don't use recursion, then, use iteration, and use this method to compare the contents for `IList` types

Comment: @RufusL could you please help me giving some code example. I am stuck for lists part. And I am not able to identify why it giving me object difference when there isn't any difference in Address and ContactDetials object. As mentioned if I comment out ContactDetails List in employeeAddress object, It behaves as expected.